# where is 【update classes and resources】 button in intellij after 2021.02?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I am using tomcat 7.0.77 for developing a java web application. Running tomcat in the debug mode, I do not have rounded arrow icon option to select "Update resources" and "Update classes and resources" on the "Services" tab.

- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build
  #IU-212.4746.92, built on July 27, 2021 Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1504.13 amd64

Please, could you help find them? Thanks a lot in advance! It would save me a lot of time..

[image: Run Configuration Tomcat]
[image: Services Tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its a bug. The work around solution meanwhile. Go through the URL

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274540?_ga=2.107717894.502399384.1629436616-503816475.1629436616

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are deploying the artifact of an **exploded type** in **Deployment** tab of Tomcat Run/Debug Configuration. Then you will have an ability to use **Update classes and resources** option for the **Update** action:

[image]

2. Use Run | Debugging Actions | **Update `<run configuration name>`** action in the Main menu.

Comment: In services tab i cannot see the rounded arrow icon ,click will get a popup with options of dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

just remove and update tomcat
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLTS2.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  As it is written, your answer is a bit unclear.

If you are saying that the issue is fixed in a newer release, then you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78187020/edit) your answer to make that clear.  Consider including the version information in which the problem is fixed.  [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  I suggest reading some highly voted answers for examples.  Thanks!